# facepy picture posting not visible

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facepy

I am attempting to use [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) to post pictures to my Facebook timeline with Public permissions.

I have set up a Facebook app for development and use that to generate OAuth tokens that are used for authentication for my script. The posts show up as having been posted by that app (I just submitted the app for review with the hope that might fix my problem).

I can get facepy to post pictures and can see them when I visit my timeline. They even appear to have public permissions when I click on the permissions for the post.

However, when I use the "View As" feature of Facebook and look at my timeline from a public viewpoint, I cannot view the pictures. I can see the post I made myself for the announcement of the pictures that will automatically be posted, but I cannot see the pictures that are automatically posted.

As a short example of how I'm posting the images:

```
graph = facepy.GraphAPI(<oauth token>)
graph.post('me/photos', source=open('kitten1.jpg', 'rb'), message='The first kitten')
```

Comment: Don't submit. Just mark the app as live under Review and Status

Comment: @WizKid That did it, and I can't believe I missed it. Thanks!